# JSON string to UTF8 in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, lumen

My previous question was closed and marked as already answered by another. It does not help and I still have a problem. deceze, perhaps read the question before you close it.

I've read multiple questions on this and the answer is just to use `utf8_encode` but that's not working in my case. I've added `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` to the `json_decode` which also doesn't help. I even saw one which applied to Lumen where you added `['Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Charset' => 'utf-8']` to your response, and that didn't work either.

```
$ship_id_chunks = array_chunk($ship_id_array, 100);
$ship_array = array();

foreach ($ship_id_chunks as $chunk) {
    $ids = $chunk;
    $chunk = implode(",", $chunk);
    $json = file_get_contents($uri);
    $data = json_decode($json, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)["data"];
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $name = $data[$id]["name"];
        if (!empty($name)) {
            echo "$name, "; // Here to test name value. Correct here!
            array_push($ship_array, $name);
        }
    }
}
echo PHP_EOL;

return response()->json($ship_array, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Charset' => 'utf-8']);
```

Some of the values in the returned JSON are `"St.\u00a0Louis"`, `"V\u00e4ster\u00e5s"`, and `"\u00d6sterg\u00f6tland"`. There are a fair few more of these.

As you can see in the code above, I added an `echo` to print the name and the values are correct there. It's only when it gets returned through Lumen that it's wrong.

I even added a `array_map("utf8_encode", $ship_array)` before the return and had no luck there either.

If someone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to be an issue with Lumen, and not the `json_decode`.

Changing the return statement to the below solves this issue.

```
return response()->json($ship_array, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Charset' => 'utf-8'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```